# Google Data Transfer from S3-compatible sources MissingRegion

Tags: google-cloud-storage, file-transfer

Mainly wondering if anyone has encountered before (and how to resolve).

Transfer job from s3-compatible source to Cloud Storage fails. Unable to list objects from the source.
Agent logs show
W0111 06:49:13.002952       8 helpers.go:465 got unknown FailureType: UNKNOWN_FAILURE, MissingRegion: could not find region configuration

I have been following the guide https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/s3-compatible
Source is non-Amazon S3-compatible storage service. Source has been tested with other S3 client tools (including gsutil).

Appears AWS SDK for Go is in use
https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/configuring-sdk/
The SDK requires a region to operate but does not have a default Region.

Amazon S3-compatible storage services (MinIO, Hitichai Content Platform) do not require a region.

I have tried passing AWS_REGION, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variables to Agent running in Docker. Mounting ~/.aws/config in the container.

SDK may require both of these to be done
Set the AWS_REGION environment variable to the default Region
Set the region explicitly using config.WithRegion as an argument to config.LoadDefaultConfig when loading configuration.

Thanks

Comment: I'm running into the same issue when using the Google Storage Transfer agent to move data from MinIO to GCS. Setting the AWS_REGION and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variables doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's still seeing the MissingRegion error, specifying the **Signing region** when setting up the transfer job would make the agent grab content from S3 compatible object storage properly. The value should be your target GCS bucket location.

Comment: Confirmed. Adding the GCS bucket location in the source Signing Region allowed the transfer job to succeed. Thank you